# Nesting controllers in Code Igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using a CI class which extends the core CI_LOADER allowing me to load a template within a template:

```
$this->load->view('wrapper','category',$data);
```

This loads a template of category in to the master template wrapper.

This means in the controllers I have to make sure I always populate any data that needs to be fed in to the wrapper view as well as the inner view. So all of my classes include methods which are needed to pull in stuff like the dynamic navigation and categories which are displayed in the wrapper view...then in my controllers that are generating the inner view I have to call these methods and assign them as output.

My controllers can end up looking like this:

```
public function product_listing($store,$category,$product_slug) {
    //These are all needed to populate the wrapper view
    $data['categories'] = $this->get_categories();
    $data['navigation'] = $this->navigation();
    $data['cart'] = $this->get_cart();
    $data['store'] = $store;
    //Then this is needed for the inner view        
    $data['products'] = $this->model_products>get_product($store,$category,$product_slug);
    $data['title'] = $data['products'][0]->product_name;
}
```

My question is, is there any way to load this stuff in some sort of wrapper class to avoid polluting each of my classes with methods (and calls to these methods from within other methods as above) that are needed for the wrapper view.

Comment: why not do it all in the constructor of the controller, store the results in a class member variable which is an array, and then in each function of the controller do something like $data['navigation'] = $this->navigation;  ?  This way all of your nav stuff would be available in your views from $navigation['key']

Comment: by default, you can make $this->load->view from inside a view, wouldn´t that be enough for your template engine? This way, your controllers would need to pass the data to only one view (the main view or the 'template' view) and that view would pass the data as needed to its 'sub-views'